# Python: How can I take a list of lists, convert every element into strings, and return the list of lists?

Tags: python

For example:

```
list = [[11,2,3,5],[5,3,74,1,90]]
```

returns the same thing, only everything is a str instead of an int.
I want to be able to use .join on them. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside don't call your list `list`, as this will clash with the python keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python and str the "item" in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only ever go 2 lists deep:

```
>>> l = [[11, 2, 3, 5], [5, 3, 74, 1, 90]]
>>> [[str(j) for j in i] for i in l]
[['11', '2', '3', '5'], ['5', '3', '74', '1', '90']]
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I had come up with something similar but it was more difficult to implement without this list comprehension. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a list-comp and `map` for this one:

```
[ map(str,x) for x in lst ]
```

---

But I suppose py3.x would need an addition `list` in there (yuck).

```
[ list(map(str,x)) for x in lst ]
```

---

As a side note, you can't use `join` on this list we return anyway.  I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

```
for x in lst:
   print ("".join(x))
```

If that's the case, you can forgo the conversion all together and just do it when you're joining:

```
for x in lst:
   print ("".join(str(item) for item in x))
```